# Is there any good 3d engine exists for winrt applications?

Tags: c#, 3d, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

i want to do some complex 3d transformations in my winrt application, i found this is possible with **Matrix3DProjection**,but it is really hard to understand. is there any alternate for this for winrt applications?

Answer (score 2):

I expect you should be using [DirectX](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wingameswithdirectx/threads) which should work across all Windows 8 based platforms.

Comment: It would help your answer if you were to give some information on why you think DirectX is suitable

Answer (score 1):

[Ogre3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/) has a WinRT renderer. It is one of the most widely used open source 3d engines and has a permissive license.

Answer (score 0):

If your budget allows i will recommend [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/) it is easy to learn professional engine that targets pretty much all platforms from PC to IOS and flash player. Also it has development tools and huge community.

Comment: It looks like Unity just released support for Windows Store apps (as in, today).  But it's still in the "Early Access" phase:  http://blogs.unity3d.com/2013/03/07/unity-4-early-access-for-windows-store-apps/